# copy file from folder in user abc to a root folder

Tags: 16.04, command-line, directory, root, users

As user **abc**, I had wanted to install a "**systemrescuecd.iso**" on a USB stick. I had made a temporary folder "***/tmp/cdrom***" (command: mkdir -p /tmp/cdrom). But the command:

```
mount -o loop,exec /path/to/systemrescuecd-x86-x.y.z.iso /tmp/cdrom
```

failed, as root was required.

As **root**, I again made the temporary folder. But I do not know the path addressed from **root** to the user **abc** folder containing the .iso file.
Once I have copied this .iso file into **/tmp/cdrom**, will the mount command be successful?

Comment: I somehow think this a [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Where exactly is the iso file located? In `abc`'s home directory? E.g. `/home/abc/systemrescuecd-x86-x.y.z.iso`?

Comment: /tmp/cdrom is the mountpoint, so don't copy the file there. Maybe you could copy it to /tmp instead? And keep in mind you would need to change the path in the mount command.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to contain the full output of the commands you executed. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). Have you tried to mount it elsewhere (e.g. the [standard location `/mnt`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/mnt.html))?

Answer (score 1):

if you, as user **abc**, type the command `pwd` (print working directory), it will show you the path to the directory you are in

Also using `sudo` in front ofthe mount command will execute the command with "root rights".

Comment: The iso file is indeed located in abc's home directory.